# How to use Capybara 'visit' with domain constrained routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, capybara, vcr

I have domain constrained routes in my rails app:

```
constraints domain_constraints do
  # Routes definition goes here
end
```

And I want to use capybara `visit` to visit those route. I tried to set `Capybara.default_host` and `Capybara.app_host` to one of my virtual host domain, but still not working.

I also tried to use `selenium-webdriver`, to allow visit outside url, but also using VCR which prevent outside url connection.

Thanks for anyone who can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up VCR to ignore your domain.

https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/configuration/ignore-request#ignored-host-requests-are-not-recorded-and-are-always-allowed